# SQL Server Index on VarChar(50) - Is this fulltext? Or what?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

What exactly happens when I create an index in my SQL Server 2008 DB on a VarChar column. This is obviously a text column.

Will it be automatically fulltext indexed or does it create a different kind of index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Full-text indexes are different from normal indexes. Consider these two seemingly equivalent where clauses:

```
WHERE [mycolumn] LIKE '%' + @MyValue + '%'

WHERE CONTAINS([mycolumn], @MyValue)
```

The former will *not* use *any* index, even a normal one of the sort you refer to in your question.  It is not considered **[sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)**.  The latter specifically tells the server to use a full-text index.

On the other hand, this will work with a normal index, but ignores any available full-text index:

```
WHERE [mycolumn] LIKE @MyValue + '%'
```

Normal indexes work because they are *ordered*.  When you go to lookup a value in the index, you can use a binary search, b*-tree, or similar algorithm to more-quickly find or reject your match, and when comparing for a join or range the server can 'walk' the index to efficiently check a number of values.

Full-text indexes cannot just be ordered, because you have to be able to search in the middle of the content as quickly as in the beginning.  Thus they are much [more complicated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).

Answer (score 1):

no you have to create a fulltext index column for that type of searching.  it is not created automatically with a normal index.

Comment: What is the normal index doing then?